# How to update 3 tables 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am currently running three quires but want to run only single query to update is it possible:

```
update a set a.a='xxx' where a.b='123;
update b set b.a='xxx' where b.b='123';
update c set b.a='xxx' where b.b='123';
```

***Note***:  'xxx' and '123' i.e. data is same in there queries and column name 'a' and 'b' are also same names three tables

Comment: What's wrong with three queries?

Answer (score 2):

Join the tables in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE a
INNER JOIN b ON b.b = a.b
INNER JOIN c ON c.b = a.b
SET a.a = 'xxx',
    b.a = 'xxx',
    c.a = 'xxx'
WHERE a.b = '123';
```

This will work only if there are rows with `a = 'xxx'` in all 3 tables but I don't expect it to be better in performance than the 3 separate queries.
See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b5345913e699cd530bf6c56f8605b23).